# Formula for two sided principal ideal for a ring without unity

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, rngs

> How to express, the two sided principal ideal of a ring without unity(Rng)?

> How to express, the two sided ideal of a ring $R$ generated by some subset $S\subseteq R$ where $R$ is ring without unity(Rng).

**My attempt**:  For first one, when $R$ is ring with unity then the two sided principal ideal of $R$ is given by

$RaR=\{r_1as_1+...+r_nas_n : r_1,s_1,...r_n,s_n\in R\},$

For some element $a\in R$.

But, when $R$ is ring without unity then $a$ may not belongs to $RaR$. So how to write/represent the two sided principal ideal in this case? Is it is given by $RaR+a\mathbb{Z}$ (**am i correct?**).

Further what about second question? Please help....

Comment: Did you mean $a\Bbb{Z}$ rather than $n\Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Stahl yes i mean $a\mathbb{Z}$